# JpaRepository findByFieldEquals ignores case

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a controller that calls a JpaRepository derived query method, I thought it was supposed to be case sensitive by default and from google I've only found options to add case insensitivity to the query, but not the case sensitivity. In my code it finds and returns rows from database regardless of case. Is it a bug or i don't know something ?

Controller code:

```
    System.out.println(nickname);
    User invitedUser = userService.findByNickname(nickname);
    System.out.println(invitedUser);
```

JpaRepository code:

```
Optional<User> findByNicknameEquals(String nickname);
```

I have tried just `findByNickname` but result was the same

UserService code:

```
public User findByNickname(String nickname){
    Optional<User> result = userRepository.findByNicknameEquals(nickname);

    User user;

    if(result.isPresent()){
        user = result.get();
    }else{
        user = null;
    }
    return user;
}
```

what gets printed by the sout() from controller:

[image]

Comment: Which database you are using ? and What is the datatype in database ?

Comment: MySql 8.0.18, this is the User table

CREATE TABLE users (
  `googlesub` varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
  `creation_datetime` DATETIME not null,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `role` VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar (16) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`googlesub`),
  KEY (`nickname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Add the query logged in application log and add user  entity also

Comment: Used charset (`latin1`) for the table is case insensitive. Related question: [How to do a case sensitive search in WHERE clause?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15250/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing default charset and collation on database tables:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

before this I had this charset, this is what made it ignore case.

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```